# Script loses permission in the magic method __destruct()

Tags: php

I tried to create a file on object instantiation and create another on object destruction.

Here is the code:

```
class Foo{
    public function __construct(){
        file_put_contents('a_construct.txt', 'c');
    }
    public function __destruct(){
        file_put_contents('a_destruct.txt', 'd');
    }
}
```

The `a_construct.txt` file is normally created. But when it comes to creating the `a_destruct.txt` file, it behaves weirdly.

If I run the following code, the 'a_destruct' file does **not** get created.

```
$foo = new Foo();
```

And I get this error:

> **Warning:** file_put_contents(a_destruct.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied

---

Now, If I run the following and check the folder, the file is there.

```
$foo = new Foo();
unset($foo);
```

---

What I have tried:

- Swapping the names from `construct` to `destruct` and back, but it always works only for the `__construct` method;
- Adding an output on the methods to confirm that they are being called - they are (and for both test codes).

The second test-code shows me that I **do** have permissions to create a file.

But the second topic tells me that I'm 'loosing' permissions when I let the object be destroyed at the end of the script (since I made sure the method was being called).

---

What's causing this and how to fix?

Comment: This has little mention in the docs, so I decided to post it here with a bit more details and a way to fix the issue hoping that I can help somebody in the future (As I needed this solution myself). From [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), _"it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged"_.

Comment: It could also happen that the file gets created without errors, not in the expected directory, but any directory up the tree). Both problems have the same cause, explained in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To **fix** it, you can use the complete path:

```
public function __destruct(){
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/a_destruct.txt', 'd');
}
```

---

This is documented in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor):

> The working directory in the script shutdown phase can be different with some SAPIs (e.g. Apache).

---

What that means is that you are trying to create a file in a different directory - and a directory you don't have permission to.

And that's why it works when you run `unset($foo)` - because it's not yet in the shutdown phase.

---

Although I **wouldn't recommend** messing with working dir *at shutdown phase*, I feel like showing that it's possible:

```
public function __destruct(){
    $tmp = getcwd(); // get current working dir
    chdir(dirname(__FILE__)); // set it to be same as the file
    file_put_contents('a_destruct.txt', 'd');
    chdir($tmp); // set the working dir back to what it was before
}
```